# Reading files inside a jar?

Tags: java, file, jar

I know this has been asked many times but I'm having a problem here. I want to be able to read a custom file type line by line so I can do things like save and load. Can anyone write a small piece of code to show me how to do this?

Here is how I wanted to read it:

```
//Here is where the code to get the file should be

while((String text = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    if (text.startsWith("add"))
    //ect
}
```

Comment: 1. Do you need to read the binary file or text file?

Comment: 2. Is it problem for you to open file?

Comment: I'm trying to read a text based file.

Comment: I'm trying to open the file.

Comment: Trying *how* to open the file? Where is the file? What's the problem? What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

Jar files are ZIP files which contains all java compiled class files and other material. In order to read files inside JAR files, you have to be able to read zip files. An example is here:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

public class ReadZip {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      ZipFile zf = new ZipFile("ReadZip.zip");
      Enumeration entries = zf.entries();

      BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        ZipEntry ze = (ZipEntry) entries.nextElement();
        System.out.println("Read " + ze.getName() + "?");
        String inputLine = input.readLine();   // your code here

 }
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

from: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/ReadingtheContentsofaZIPFile.htm

Comment: This is a little heavy handed, BUT, would be required if the Jar file isn't within the applications classLoader context

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the jar we are talking about is your application or one of your application's dependencies, this should work

```
BufferedReader br  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream(path)));
```

path - path to the file in the jar, e.g. "/test/test.txt"

Answer (score 1):

To open file from the jar resources see: [Class#getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).

Code example to read text file:

```
    try {
        InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("resource name"); // get binary stream to resource
        // InputStream in = new FileInputStream("filePath"); //in case file loaded from the FileSystem
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.startsWith("add")) {
                // e.t.c.
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        //process exception or throw up
    }
```

---

It is easier to load file from resources using [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Resources.html):

```
URL url = Resources.getResource(resourceName);
List<String> text = Resources.readLines(url, Charsets.UTF_8);
```